# MP and RN Spacetime in Intra-Universe Wormhole Metric

Tags: metric-tensor, boundary-conditions, wormholes, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I want to make sure I correctly understand what [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9606069) is saying. It sounds like it is talking about a two-body Majumdar-Papapetrau outer metric that switches to RN once you enter either of the spherical boundaries. If I understand correctly, it is a case of gluing those parts of the RN metric whose $r$ and $\theta$ values fall within the spheres to that part of the MP metric.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms in title.

Comment: MP is Majumdar-Papapetrau, RN is Reissner-Nordstrom.